# In angular from ts file not getting the data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

demo.component.ts

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({

      selector: 'app-demo',

      templateUrl: './demo.component.html',

      styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css']
    })

    export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

       product : Object[]

      constructor() { 

        this.product=[
          {
            id: "1",
            name :"tiger"
          },
          {

          id: "2",
          name :"loin"
          }
        ];
      }
    public getProducts(){
      this.product;
    }
      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

demo.coponent.ts

```
<h1>

    <div *ngFor="let product of getProducts()">
        <p>{{product.id}}</p> 
        <p>{{product.name}}</p>

    </div>
</h1>
```

I am new to angular. From the HTML. I am not able to retrieve the data from the function. In Console getting any error messages.

but by using the product, I am able to get the data

```
<div *ngFor="let product of product">
        <h1>{{product.id}}</h1> 
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>

    </div>
```

Comment: Add return statement in getProducts(). The definition of function should  look like { return this.product; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
getProducts = ()=> this.product;
```

Or you can just add the return  statement to the existing function like this

```
function getProducts(){
     return  this.product;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using functions in html is not recommended. You should skip this method and use `product` property in html.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return using the **`return`** keyword

```
public getProducts(){
   return this.product;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't require to call a function from .html for getting data and it's not recommended that way. What you are doing is fine here and can go with that:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of product">
    <h1>{{product.id}}</h1> 
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

You are able to access the product array from .html and then there is no point of writing one more function to get product array.

And, you missed return statement in function.

Comment: Using functions in html is not recommended because, after any rendered view, these functions have to be executed again.

Comment: @Kamil Augustyniak I totally agree with that.